# Understanding branch prediction and how predictors are selected

Tags: optimization, cpu, cpu-architecture, branch-prediction

I don't think this is a duplicate, as this question is regarding how to write optimal code to cater to the branch predictor, as well as validating my personal understanding of how it works in general.

#### So, here's my general understanding of how BP works, and please tell me if any part is incorrect:

When a branch is encountered, the CPU attempts to guess whether it will be taken.

This guess is based on which predictor is used, and predictors base their guess on one or more of the following:

- The previous times that this branch has/has not been taken (local dynamic)
- The previous branches-taken (global dynamic)
- Naive assumption (static prediction)

Also, from what I understand, prediction is based on the instructions themselves, and not any instance data.

As an example of what i mean, please consider the following vector `append` snippet:

```rs
fn append<T>(&mut self, element: T) {
    if self.length == self.capacity {
        self.double_capacity()
    }
    self[self.length] = element
    self.length += 1
}
```

Whether the `if` will be taken is guessed based on what happens on any global invocation, rather than the branch history for a given vector instance.

There's also the question of monomorphization, which, to my understanding, would produce multiple compiled versions of this function, effectively permitting a branch predictor for each generic type that is used

#### Here's my main question regarding BP:

It seems like in this snippet, a static branch predictor would be optimal, since the lowest accuracy would be `1 - 1/(default_vec_size)` (about 94% for a default capacity of 16), and only get more accurate as the vectors became larger.

But how does the CPU pick whether to use a static, local dynamic, or global dynamic predictor here?

Is it just based on runtime analysis, or are there some intrinsics introduced by the programmer/compiler to hint at what should be used?

Comment: Generally, the static prediction is only used if the dynamic prediction misses (there's no prediction because the branch was never hit before or has been pushed out by other branches).  When there's more than one kind of dynamic prediction, they generally run in parallel and whichever one hits is used (and will push out the other(s), with adjustments for mispredictions)

Comment: As far as stuff the compiler can do, it depends on the ISA -- some have bits in the branch instructions that can specify the static prediction or even inhibit the use of dynamic prediction for those specific branches.  But that is actually rare.

Comment: Modern microarchitectures (like Intel since Haswell which use IT-TAGE predictors) apparently never do static prediction; there's *always* a prediction from the dynamic predictor, whether it's appropriate for this branch or not.  (For infrequently-hit cases, it won't be if it aliases with any more frequent cases that go a different way.)  [Why did Intel change the static branch prediction mechanism over these years?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51822731)

Comment: @Jam: https://blog.cloudflare.com/branch-predictor looks good.  https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/05/amds-zen-4-part-1-frontend-and-execution-engine/ mentions some about multi-level branch predictors, like Zen 4 uses, where a fast but less accurate predictor provides an initial guess about branch direction. 
 (CPUs also need to predict where to fetch from next, before the current block is even decoded to find the *existence* of branch instructions.  The cloudflare blog I linked mentions that.)